# Как корректно добавить версии одной библиотеки для разных архитектур?

Tags: android, gradle

У меня есть 4 версии библиотеки для разных архитектур:

1. lib_arm7.aar
2. lib_arm8.jar
3. lib_x86.aar
4. lib_x86_64.aar

Как мне их правильно добавить?
Я добавил эти файлы в папку libs и добавил следующую строку для build.gradle:

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar','*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
```

Но я получаю следующую ошибку:

```
Error: Program type already present:"какой-то класс из либы"
```

Если оставить только одну версию либы, то этой ошибки нет